# Reading List in other browsers?

Tags: safari, icloud, reading-list

Is there a Reading List extension for Chrome? I have a deep, dark hatred of Safari, but Reading List seems more convenient than Pocket of Readability. Or, is there a way to access it by any non-safari means at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All reading list is a simple wrapper around bookmarks, that allows you quick access to both add and remove entries.  It's usefulness stops there really, and the matter of convenience boils down to what you want to use the stored pages for, and how you wish to access them.  If you are just using the same computer and will always have a net connection, then yes it's very convenient, but if you want to have them stored offline and synced to multiple devices, then it's not so useful.

I don't use Chrome, but I would probably look to get an extension  for either Pocket/Readability/Instapaper to mimic the reading list feature, by making your recently stored pages available from a toolbar button rather than having to login to the respective sites.  This gives you all the added benefits of using a proper 'service', with the instant nature of a quick bookmark system.  A quick search for "instapaper" yielded 50 results on the [Chrome extension store thing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions)

Comment: Doesn't "answer" much, but clarifies a lot :D

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. Reading List downloads the pages and makes them accessible offline, so they’re much more convenient now.

Comment: Yep, the Reading List also syncs between your devices, which is very handy when saving something to read later on a phone.

Answer (score 18):

To add the active tab in Google Chrome to Safari's reading list:

Adapted from a comment by tzarskyz on: [Add a URL from Chrome to Safari's reading list](https://gist.github.com/pdxmph/1342437)

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set pageUrl to get URL of active tab of first window
end tell
tell application "Safari" to add reading list item pageUrl
display notification pageUrl with title "Added to Reading List"
```

Open AppleScript Editor and save the above code as a new script.  From that point on, you can run this script to add the active tab in Google Chrome to Safari's reading list.  You can trigger this action via Terminal (`osascript`), by double-clicking the script (in Terminal or on your desktop), via an app launcher like [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/), via [Fastscripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), etc.

Enjoy your reading! :)

[image]

---

Update: I've since found a better way to accomplish this, without requiring something like Fastscripts.  Simply use OS X's built-in application, Automator.  You can adapt the steps outlined at the following link to run the AppleScript I included above: [Global HotKey for Pause/Play,Next Song, etc.](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Global-HotKey-for-Pause-Play-Next-Song-etc/idc-p/74537#M4939)

Comment: This is awesome -- I added this exact script to my documents and run Alfred to quickly save to Reading List. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it helped, @mjb!  Have a great day, and happy reading! :)

Comment: The script worked for me but with a minor modification - remove "Google" so it is just "Chrome" Tell application "Chrome" set pageUrl to get URL of active tab of first window
end tell
tell application "Safari" to add reading list item pageUrl
display notification pageUrl with title "Added to Reading List"

Comment: I'd recommend to close Safari afterwards since we're not doing anything with it there is no need to keep it open. Add this to the eend of your script `tell application "Safari" to quit`

Comment: This worked with better touch tool as well to create a keyboard shortcut using this script

Answer (score 11):

You can add things with AppleScript according to this: http://jga.me/blog/2011/10/18/applescript-readinglist

So it should be easy to cook up a Firefox extension to call that bit of AppleScript, you can call it form the shell like:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to add reading list item "http://totl.net/"'
```

Which will cause Safari to generate the preview and send it to iCloud, or wherever it goes to.

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac the reading list is stored in `/Users/notjonathan/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` so potentially there is a tool out there to read them automatically. The actual syncing is done by Safari. It doesn't just watch the file for changes and upload the changes. You actually have to make the changes from within Safari.

So what you're "stuck" with using services like Pocket, which although slightly less convenient in iOS safari, is imo better. Especailly as other apps, e.g. Tweetbot can integrate with Pocket, but not Safari Reading List.

There is bookmarklet for Pocket [available](http://getpocket.com/add), which you can use in iOS Safari to quickly add pages, with just a few more presses than pressing Add To Reading List.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a fork of CloudyTabs with Reading list support, clone it at https://github.com/cl3m/CloudyTabs

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in Service to add a URL to the Reading List. Just select the URL by clicking on the address bar, then menu > Firefox > Services > Add to Reading List.

It's possible to add a global keyboard shortcut for the Service: System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Select the service in the list and add a key combo.

Comment: I thought this would work, but I just get 'No services apply' (this is Catalina 10.15.7, with Firefox 110), despite Reading List being enabled in System Preferences. And also it works if I highlight or copy a URL in other third-party apps :(

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition here.  I love the small menu application called PopClip.  It enables many different functions to be peformed on highlighted text.  One such add-on function is: "Add to reading list."  Worked like a charm for me (and is system wide- so even links within e-mails can be added).  Apple AppStore app maker's page: https://pilotmoon.com/popclip/